# how to build auto_arima with seasonality using historical data

Tags: auto, arima

I have 5 years of temperature data in 15 mins slot, with that I want to forecast for the next 2 days.. I am confused of p,d,q and P,D,Q values in ARIMA

Comment: Did you already try something? Results?

Answer (score 0):

Use auto.arima() it will automatically find best value of p,d,q.
Therefore no need to specify manually.

Comment: But do we need to call this every time data changes? Like once he gets data for today, how to update the model? Or we can update model with new values??

Comment: If we change data every time then we have to run model everytime.